# How do I run a application on top/in a display manager like GDM?

Tags: display-manager

I was wondering if there is a way to run a application like [Onboard](https://launchpad.net/onboard) on a display manager like [GDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager).  If it depends on the display manager than please post the [GDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager) instructions, or all of the popular display managers.  The reason why I need [Onboard](https://launchpad.net/onboard) running while using [GDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager) is I am learning the [Dvorak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard) keyboard layout...

**Please Note**
I know there is an on-screen keyboard included in GDM. Please don't post that as an answer, I am using the keyboard as an example and would like to know how to run any application in the GDM window.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the program you would like to run to the gdm user's startup applications. As explained in the [GDM documentation](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/unstable/configuration.html.en#autostart), this is done by adding `.desktop` files to the `/usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow` directory.

Specifically, in your case, you need to create a file at `/usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/onboard.desktop` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Onboard
Comment=Onboard Keyboard
Exec=/usr/bin/onboard
```

If the `onboard` executable is not in `/usr/bin`, change the last line to point to the correct path.

Comment: For others desktop managers, replace `gdm` with `kdm` or `lightdm`, etc.