# How do I can manager and change and add anything(like : software) on a display manager like GDM before login user desktop?

Tags: gdm, display-manager

Unfortunately, I could not get an answer, so I will ask my question again.

Do the sound and keyboard settings, reset the operating system and the clock, as well as the various options of the desktop environment related to the display manager like GDM?
is it right?
if it isn't, then How I can access options and changes?

My goal: run and launch any software and change options in a display manager like GDM.

in the forum ubuntu, about this subject, I find the links, but I get don't any answer.
[How do I run a application on top/in a display manager like GDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469399/how-do-i-run-a-application-on-top-in-a-display-manager-like-gdm#469403)

some say I am not able to do this because the software cannot run without a graphical environment the forum!!!
https://www.linux.org/threads/how-i-can-launch-gnome-terminal-for-memory-forensics-before-appearing-desktop-login.41540/#post-167705

But I did it this way.
with command :

```
 # sudo xinit  /usr/bin/geany  -- :1
# sudo xinit /usr/bin/xfced4-terminal  -- :1
```

please guide me.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a application on top/in a display manager like GDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469399/how-do-i-run-a-application-on-top-in-a-display-manager-like-gdm)

Comment: @vanadium OP already noticed that post, but it didn't answer his question.

Comment: Yes, This answer does not work.
I don't know what I did wrong.

This is the link to my question.
But I do not get an answer.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/469399/how-do-i-run-a-application-on-top-in-a-display-manager-like-gdm

Comment: To be  clear you have posted the EXACT same question a second time?

Comment: @David Looks like the OP was referring to here: https://www.linux.org/threads/how-i-can-launch-gnome-terminal-for-memory-forensics-before-appearing-desktop-login.41540/ where the question was posted *twice*...